# Error in Selenium Python - Cannot create webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium (Python) to create a webdriver. It was working fine a few hours ago. But now it gives the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/local/data2/mwaqar/opt/Python-2.7.4/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/local/data2/mwaqar/opt/Python-2.7.4/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/cshome/mwaqar/AEK/AEK_extract_community.py", line 49, in extract_community
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/local/data2/mwaqar/opt/Virtual-Python-2.7.4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.33.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 61, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),
  File "/local/data2/mwaqar/opt/Virtual-Python-2.7.4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.33.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
  File "/local/data2/mwaqar/opt/Virtual-Python-2.7.4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.33.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 51, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable()
  File "/local/data2/mwaqar/opt/Virtual-Python-2.7.4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.33.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 95, in _wait_until_connectable
    self.profile.path, self._get_firefox_output()))
WebDriverException: Message: 'Can\'t load the profile. Profile Dir: /cshome/mwaqar/AEK/tmpgZ0n_J Firefox output: \n(Gecko:32421): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "clearlooks",\n*** LOG addons.xpi: startup\n*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges\n*** LOG addons.xpi: No changes found\n*** LOG addons.xpi: Add-ons list is invalid, rebuilding\n*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Opening database\n'
```

I have no idea what is causing this. Can somebody provide any pointers?

UPDATE: The code I am using is simple

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(size=(800,600), visible=0)
display.start()

driver = webdriver.Firefox() # gives exception
```

Comment: Try to disable/uninstall clearlooks addon. I think its hurting the webdriver I guess

Comment: I don't even use Firefox. If this is the issue, how was it working fine a few hours ago?

Comment: Probably you should paste the code to give better answer. I am assuming that you are running on Firefox by looking at the Exception

Comment: Added code. It's simple.

Comment: You don't have firefox browser installed on your machine?

Comment: I believe if the Firefox driver was not installed, the error would have been different. Besides, it was working fine a few hours ago.

Comment: Sorry its browser not driver. My Bad :(

Comment: Firefox browser is installed on the machine.

Comment: The error `"clearlooks",\n*** LOG addons.xpi` which shows might be problem with that addon. Please disable that addon in the extensions

Comment: I have no idea. I never used it (the browser).

Comment: BTW, I believe clearlooks is the theme engine, not the addon.

Comment: Yeah whatever.. its a theme or addon. Just disable it. Uninstall is safe. After that restart your browser and then run your webdriver code

Comment: Hmm, will try this tomorrow when I am at the machine.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem. The problem was that since I had executed the script a lot of times, therefore, many Firefox user profiles (corresponding to a webdriver instance) were present in `/tmp/` and `/var/tmp/` directories (by the name of `tmp*`). As soon as I removed these directories, the problem vanished.